# Get closest parent element by class name in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

Using React, how do I refer to parent element's closest element with certain classname?

Code below:

```
const Skill = props => (
<div className="skill-card">
    <div className="skill-header">
        <div className="skill-header-text">
            <div className="skill-header-img-container">
                <img src={require('../../img/projects/skills/' + props.skill.image)} alt={props.skill.name} className="skill-image" />
            </div>
            <div className="skill-heading"><h2 className="skill-name">{props.skill.name}</h2></div>
        </div>
        <div className="skill-header-icon">
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={"angle-" + props.angle} onClick={props.click} />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div className="skill-body">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
);

class Skills extends Component {
    ...

    handleClick = () => {
        // Add style to the closest skill-body in here!
    }
}
```

In this case, once I click the `FontAwesomeIcon`, I want the `div` element with className `skill-body` to open up.

First I thought that using states would be good, but by far all the `skill-body` elements will open up upon clicking the `FontAwesomeIcon`. My approach would be just add stylings to `skill-body` (`display: block` and `display: none`).

How can I refer to the `skill-body` inside the `Component`'s function with the `handleClick`?

EDIT:
Used HMR's functional component example, and I am still stuck.

```
const Skills = ({ skills }) => (
<div>
    {skills.map(skill => (
        <SkillContainer key={skill._id} skill={skill} />
    ))}
</div>
);

const Skill = ({ skill, open, toggle, data }) => (
    <div>
        <h4 onClick={toggle}>skill: {skill} {data.name}</h4>
        {open && <div>{data.description}</div>}
    </div>
);

const SkillContainer = ({ skill }) => {
    const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
    const [data, setData] = React.useState({ skills: [] });

    const toggle = React.useCallback(() => setOpen(open => !open), []);

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            const result = await         
                axios("http://localhost:5000/api/skills/");

        setData(result.data);
    }

    fetchData();
}, []);

return React.useMemo(() => Skill({ skill, open, toggle, data }), [open, 
skill, toggle, data]);
}

export default Skills;
```

Got to this point so far by reading the `useHook` documentations.
What I want to do, is gather data with `axios` and then set the content with it.

Comment: So in a list of Skills when you click on a certain button in a Skill you want that Skill to display extra info and when you click it again you want to hide it. In the list only one skill will ever show it's extra info or can there be more than one?

Comment: @MHR yes, exactly. there can be also more displayed at the same time, but for each component I want to be able to hide or show the information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use State in functional components like so:

```js
const Skills = ({ skills, loading }) =>
  loading ? (
    'loading'
  ) : (
    <div>
      {skills.map(skill => (
        <SkillContainer key={skill._id} skill={skill} />
      ))}
    </div>
  )

const Skill = ({ skill, open, toggle }) => (
  <div>
    <h4 onClick={toggle}>
      skill: {skill.completed} {skill.id}
    </h4>
    {open && <div>{skill.title}</div>}
  </div>
)

const SkillContainer = ({ skill }) => {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false)
  const toggle = React.useCallback(
    () => setOpen(open => !open),
    []
  )
  return React.useMemo(
    () => Skill({ skill, open, toggle }),
    [open, skill, toggle]
  )
}
//savety to not set state when component is no longer mounted
const useIsMounted = () => {
  const isMounted = React.useRef(false)
  React.useEffect(() => {
    isMounted.current = true
    return () => (isMounted.current = false)
  }, [])
  return isMounted
}

const SkillsContainer = () => {
  const [result, setResult] = React.useState({
    loading: true,
    data: []
  })
  const isMounted = useIsMounted()
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = () => {
      //cannot use async await here because Stack Overflow
      //  uses old babel
      axios
        .get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos')
        .then(result => {
          if (isMounted.current) {
            //do not set data if component is no longer mounted
            setResult({
              loading: false,
              data: result.data
            })
          }
        })
    }
    fetchData()
  }, [isMounted])

  return React.useMemo(
    () =>
      Skills({
        skills: result.data,
        loading: result.loading
      }),
    [result]
  )
}

//render app
ReactDOM.render(
  <SkillsContainer />,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.19.2/axios.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

The class version is a little more verbose:

```js
class SkillsContainer extends React.PureComponent {
  state = {
    loading: true,
    //should do error here as well
    result: []
  }
  fetchData = (
    length //arrow function auto bind to this
  ) =>
    new Promise(r =>
      setTimeout(() => r(length), 2000)
    ).then(l =>
      this.setState({
        loading: false,
        result: [...new Array(l)].map((_, i) => i+1)
      })
    )
  //if your skills array changes based on props:
  // example here: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (this.props.length !== prevProps.length) {
      this.fetchData(this.props.length)
    }
  }
  //fetch data on mount
  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchData(this.props.length)
  }
  render() {
    return this.state.loading
      ? 'loading'
      : Skills({ skills: this.state.result })
  }
}
const Skills = ({ skills }) => (
  <div>
    {skills.map((skill, id) => (
      <SkillContainer key={id} skill={skill} />
    ))}
  </div>
)
const Skill = ({ skill, open, toggle }) => (
  <div>
    <h4 onClick={toggle}>skill: {skill}</h4>
    {open && <div>extra</div>}
  </div>
)

class SkillContainer extends React.PureComponent {
  state = {
    open: false
  }
  toggle() {
    this.setState({
      open: !this.state.open
    })
  }
  render() {
    return Skill({
      skill: this.props.skill,
      open: this.state.open,
      toggle: this.toggle.bind(this)
    })
  }
}
//render app
ReactDOM.render(
  <SkillsContainer length={2} />,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

The code uses conditional rendering but you can [use props to set className as well](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-styling.html)

Comment: about that class version; how can I retrieve back-end data as state, previously I had state = { skills: []} and with componentDidMount and axios I gathered the back-end data. Inside the SkillContainer or make const Skill into a class?

Comment: @Timppa You can create Skill**s**Container (plural) and fetch the skills there in componentDidMount or componentDidUpdate

Comment: I am not sure how to accomplish this approach, how do I wrap the SkillsContainer, and do I change the render() method from SkillContainer inside the SkillsContainer?

Comment: @Timppa Skills doesn't change, it is still a dumb or [presentational component](https://redux.js.org/basics/usage-with-react/#presentational-and-container-components). You create a SkillsContainer that has the logic to fetch the data needed (or calls a function that implements it or dispatches an action). I updated my answer with a simple example, I would prefer to use functional components and `useEffect` because you now need component did update and component did mount.

Comment: edited the main post with your functional component. Can't figure out how to gather data from axios, otherwise the hide and show -methods work, but now I'm unsure how to make it work with axios request

Comment: @Timppa Updated the functional example

Comment: While using `let skills = await axios("http://localhost:5000/api/skills/");` it will show an error "Cannot read property 'map' of undefined". Tried out couple of hours different methods and console.log the problem, but couldn't solve it out. `setData(skills.data)` didn't work either. Any workaround?

Comment: @Timppa I have updated my answer, I thought React would not re render when using setState multiple times in effect but it does. Since data is undefined when initialising it and loading becomes false first it tries to render with skills as undefined (hence map of undefined doesn't exist).

Comment: Finally got it working with my own route. Apologies for not being clear enough at the beginning (didn't know the Axios wouldn't work with the previous approaches). Thanks a alot! :)

Answer (score 0):

I would like to pass the skill body element ref to the Parent so that you can handle the style for the element. Hope the below code would done the thing which you need.

```
class Skill extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="skill-card">
            <div className="skill-header">
                <div className="skill-header-icon">
                   <div onClick={() => this.props.click(this.skillBodyEle)}>Header Icon</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div
            ref={e => this.skillBodyEle = e}
            className="skill-body">
                Skill Body
            </div>
        </div>
            );
    }
}

class Skills extends React.Component {
    handleClick = (skillBodyEle) => {
        if (skillBodyEle.hidden) {
            skillBodyEle.hidden = false;
        } else {
            skillBodyEle.hidden = true;
        }
      };
      render() {
          return (
          <Skill 
            click={this.handleClick} 
          />
          );
      }
}
```

Comment: Should not jQuery this, [that is not what refs are intended for](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#when-to-use-refs). Just use props or state.

Answer (score 0):

Inside of handleClick(), you can manipulate the DOM to make it work:

```
const ele = document.getElementsByClassName('skill-body')[0];

if (ele.visibility === 'hidden') {
  ele.visibility = 'visible';
}
else {
  ele.visibility = 'hidden';
}
```

However, I recommend using props/state like the other answers said in order to achieve your task.