# Update var before render() [React Native]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

For a study project, I am currently developing a mobile application for reading QR Code in native React. Once a QR Code is scanned, I keep its id in memory in a history.

When I click on this id I want to open a page containing info about this QR code (retrieved by an API rest).
But when I select an ID, the information obtained is that of the previous QR code.

I have created a button that updates the information, but I would like it to be directly the right one.

Thank you, I attach my code and the git of my project.

GIT : https://github.com/davidsio/react

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Text} from 'react-native';
import QRCode from 'react-native-qrcode-svg';


let getJSON = function(url, callback) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET', url, true);
  xhr.responseType = 'json';
  xhr.onload = function() {
    var status = xhr.status;
    if (status === 200) {
      callback(null, xhr.response);
    } else {
      callback(status, xhr.response);
    }
  };
  xhr.send();
};




export default class Informations extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Informations',
    headerBackTitle: 'Retour',
    headerStyle: {
      backgroundColor: '#557aca',
      //Sets Header color
    },
    headerTintColor: '#fff',
    //Sets Header text color
    headerTitleStyle: {
      fontWeight: 'bold',
      //Sets Header text style
    },
    //Sets Header text of Status Bar
  };



  render() {

    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;

    const { params } = this.props.navigation.state;
    const itemValue = params ? params.itemValue : null;
    const itemId = params ? params.itemId : null;

    getJSON('http://elarnes.fr/get_qrcode.php?idQrCode=' + JSON.stringify(itemValue).replace(/['"]+/g, '').split(';')[1],
    function(err, data) {
      if (err !== null) {
        console.log('Something went wrong: ' + err);
      } else {
        tabCode = data[0]
      }
    });

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <QRCode
                  value={JSON.stringify(itemValue).replace(/['"]+/g, '')}
                  size={250}
                  color="black"
                  backgroundColor="white"
                  logoSize={30}
                  logoMargin={2}
                  logoBorderRadius={15}
                  logoBackgroundColor="yellow"
                />
                <Text>

                {tabCode["code"]}
                {tabCode["description"]}

                </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center'

  },
});
```

Comment: You can use componentDidMount and componentDidUpdate, an example can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60590793/1641941), the second example uses class components. You are currently expecting asynchronous result to be available in synchronous code and even if you did it correctly you would have to set state in render which is a [no no](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#render)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you try this:

```js
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        loaded: false,
        code: []
    };
}

componentDidMount() {
    getJSON('http://elarnes.fr/get_qrcode.php?idQrCode=' + JSON.stringify(itemValue).replace(/['"]+/g, '').split(';')[1],
        (err, data) => {
            if (err !== null) {
                console.log('Something went wrong: ' + err);
            } else {
                this.setState({
                    code: data[0],
                    loaded: true
                })
            }
        }
    );
}

componentDidUpdate(nextProps) {
    //this will triggered when the props changes - not needed for this
}

render() {
    if (!this.state.loaded)
        return <View />
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <QRCode
            />
            <Text>

                {tabCode["code"]}
                {tabCode["description"]}

            </Text>
        </View>
    )
}
```

Comment: setState in render? You better use componentDidMount, possibley and componentDidUpdate

Comment: [The documentaton](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#render) states `The render() function should be pure, meaning that it does not modify component state`

Comment: @Finki Thanks for your help, I tried your code, but I have an error 'this.setState is not a function'. When I searched i saw for componentDidMount & Update but i don't understand how it works. I'm a newbie in react please be merciful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Davi i updated my answer let me know if the works for you

Comment: @Finki Thanks that works, I post my final code in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Text, Button} from 'react-native';
import QRCode from 'react-native-qrcode-svg';

let code = [];


let getJSON = function(url, callback) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET', url, true);
  xhr.responseType = 'json';
  xhr.onload = function() {
    var status = xhr.status;
    if (status === 200) {
      callback(null, xhr.response);
    } else {
      callback(status, xhr.response);
    }
  };
  xhr.send();
};



export default class Informations extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Informations',
    headerBackTitle: 'Retour',
    headerStyle: {
      backgroundColor: '#557aca',
      //Sets Header color
    },
    headerTintColor: '#fff',
    //Sets Header text color
    headerTitleStyle: {
      fontWeight: 'bold',
      //Sets Header text style
    },
    //Sets Header text of Status Bar
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        loaded: false,
        code: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const { params } = this.props.navigation.state;
    const itemValue = params ? params.itemValue : null;
    const itemId = params ? params.itemId : null;

    getJSON('http://elarnes.fr/get_qrcode.php?idQrCode=' + JSON.stringify(itemValue).replace(/['"]+/g, '').split(';')[1],
        (err, data) => {
            if (err !== null) {
                console.log('Something went wrong: ' + err);
            } else {
                this.setState({
                  code: data[0],
                  loaded: true,

                })
            }
        }
    );
  }

  componentDidUpdate(nextProps) {
    //this will triggered when the props changes - not needed for this
  }

  render() {

    if (!this.state.loaded)
        return <View />
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <QRCode
                  value={"sdbwfhjk"}
                  size={250}
                  color="black"
                  backgroundColor="white"
                  logoSize={30}
                  logoMargin={2}
                  logoBorderRadius={15}
                  logoBackgroundColor="yellow"
                />
                <Text>

                {this.state.code["code"]}
                {this.state.code["description"]}

                </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center'

  },
});
```